# The variable result is not defined

Tags: applescript

I am really new to AppleScript coding and I was wondering what is going wrong with this code. The error is "The variable result is not defined."  Why is the error happening?  My code is below:

```
display dialog "Hello and welcome to my app!" buttons {"Login", "Quit"} default button 1

if the button returned of the result is "Login" then
    display dialog "Username:" buttons {"Raphi", "Guest"} default button 1 with title      "Choose user"
else
    tell application "My app" to quit
end if
if the button returned of the result is "Raphi" then
display dialog "Password:" default answer "" buttons {"Submit"} with title "Enter    password" with hidden answer
else
display dialog "You have selected guest! Guest is not currenty enabled, please ask     Raphi to enable it. Thank you!" buttons {"OK"}
end if
if the text returned of the result is "123" then
display dialog "Would you like to continue or exit?" buttons {"Continue", "Exit"}
else
display dialog "Incorrect password" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon stop
end if
if the button returned of the result is "OK" then
tell application "My app" to quit
end if
if the button returned of the result is "Continue" then
display dialog ""
else
tell application "My app" to quit
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the last few if statements, they needed to be tied together with an `else if` to get the correct structure to catch the 3 possible button choices.

Another tweak is changing `tell application "My app" to quit`, to `return`. This exits the execution of the script and will quit it (NOTE: if you save as an app, **don't** set it to **stay open**)

This will also helps while testing as it's not quitting script editor every time you run the script. Alternatively you can simplify this block with a `quit`, but i think `return` is cleaner.

See modifications below:

```
display dialog "Hello and welcome to my app!" buttons {"Login", "Quit"} default button 1

if the button returned of the result is "Login" then
    display dialog "Username:" buttons {"Raphi", "Guest"} default button 1 with title "Choose user"
else
    return
end if

if the button returned of the result is "Raphi" then
    display dialog "Password:" default answer "" buttons {"Submit"} with title "Enter    password" with hidden answer
else
    display dialog "You have selected guest! Guest is not currenty enabled, please ask     Raphi to enable it. Thank you!" buttons {"OK"}
    return
end if

if the text returned of the result is "123" then
    display dialog "Would you like to continue or exit?" buttons {"Continue", "Exit"}
else
    display dialog "Incorrect password" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon stop
end if

if the button returned of the result is "OK" then
    return
else if the button returned of the result is "Continue" then
    display dialog ""
else
    return
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
set dialogResult to display dialog ...
```

then check the return values:

```
if button returned of dialogResult is ... then
```